# set responder chain between two nsbuttons in IB

Tags: macos, cocoa, interface-builder, responder-chain

I have two nsbutton in my window.I need to link between these two in a way that,if the user press tab focus should go to the next button.

I know how the responder chain works.My Question is How to do this in interface builder.Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're looking for the `nextKeyView` outlet. Just set the `nextKeyView` outlet of one button to the button you want to be next in the tab chain.

This is nothing to do with the responder chain, by the way.

Comment: it did not worked for me initially until I changed my keyboard shortcuts system preferences by setting Full Keyboard access to all controls.

Comment: Just to be clear: System Preferences->Keyboard->Full Keyboard Control.  The only problem is ctrl+F7 can toggle this on and off.  So even if you get your interface all slick, it may act stupid by default when you distribute.  Anyone know how to have your app query this at startup and set?